# How to triage issue such as "Transaction has been automatically rolled back"

Tags: neo4j

I'm running a dedicate server for neo4j to provide REST service APIs. But found the response became slow suddenly after running a while, even we kept at same concurrent count. So I checked console.log, and found many same messages after a certain time slot:

> 2016-03-17 19:23:23.027+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111745 has been automatically rolled back.

Then I searched google and found similar symptom as  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/3h-_PCrb6p4/TB1vt2RhDgAJ. However, the method mentioned in that article doesn't work on my case. There is even no output in GC log on my case after the first "transaction roll back" message printed in console.log

**So I'd like to consult any other way that I can triage root cause of this issue?**

My server hardware config is 4CPU dual Core, 32G RAM. The database file sizes are:

```
neostore.nodestore.db: 800M byte
neostore.propertystore.db: 4G byte
neostore.relationshipstore.db: 2G byte
```

neo4j settings are like:

```
dbms.pagecache.memory=16g
wrapper.java.initmemory=8192
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192
```

console.log sample:

```
2016-03-17 18:23:23.003+0800 INFO  Successfully started database
2016-03-17 18:23:23.027+0800 INFO  Starting HTTP on port 7474 (100 threads available)
2016-03-17 18:23:23.182+0800 INFO  Enabling HTTPS on port 7473
2016-03-17 18:23:23.240+0800 WARN  Acceptors should be <= availableProcessors: ServerConnector@4a4e2faa{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0}
2016-03-17 18:23:23.254+0800 WARN  Acceptors should be <= availableProcessors: ServerConnector@618f7e63{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:0}
2016-03-17 18:23:23.272+0800 INFO  Mounting static content at /webadmin
2016-03-17 18:23:23.313+0800 INFO  Mounting static content at /browser
TeeFilter will be ACTIVE on this host [test_yaliceshi]
...
TeeFilter will be ACTIVE on this host [test_yaliceshi]
2016-03-17 18:23:24.397+0800 INFO  Remote interface ready and available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/
2016-03-17 19:23:23.027+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111745 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.028+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111747 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.028+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111749 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.028+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111748 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.028+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111758 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.029+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111763 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.029+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111762 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.030+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111764 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.030+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111767 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.030+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111771 has been automatically rolled back.
2016-03-17 19:23:23.030+0800 INFO  Transaction with id 111773 has been automatically rolled back.
```

The file end of neo4j-gc.log **(last gc output is at 19:12:12 and transaction roll back started at 19:23:23, not sure whether this is normal)**:

```
2016-03-17T19:12:06.895+0800: 2931.231: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0440391 seconds
2016-03-17T19:12:12.593+0800: 2936.929: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 322961408 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:   42475792 bytes,   42475792 total
- age   2:    3366440 bytes,   45842232 total
- age   3:     322992 bytes,   46165224 total
- age   4:     496416 bytes,   46661640 total
- age   5:     127752 bytes,   46789392 total
- age   6:     505248 bytes,   47294640 total
- age   7:     448920 bytes,   47743560 total
- age   8:     229736 bytes,   47973296 total
- age   9:      84472 bytes,   48057768 total
- age  10:     171480 bytes,   48229248 total
- age  11:     239840 bytes,   48469088 total
- age  12:      90808 bytes,   48559896 total
- age  13:     180872 bytes,   48740768 total
- age  14:     384056 bytes,   49124824 total
- age  15:     252528 bytes,   49377352 total
, 0.0441110 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 39.3 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 2936928.9, Avg: 2936928.9, Max: 2936928.9, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.8, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1.5, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 4.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 3.8, Avg: 4.3, Max: 4.5, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 17.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 24, Avg: 29.8, Max: 35, Diff: 11, Sum: 119]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.5, Avg: 0.6, Max: 0.7, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 2.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 33.2, Avg: 33.2, Max: 33.3, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 133.0]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.2]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 39.1, Avg: 39.2, Max: 39.2, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 156.6]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 2936968.1, Avg: 2936968.1, Max: 2936968.1, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.4 ms]
   [Code Root Migration: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 3.7 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 2.1 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.2 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.9 ms]
   [Eden: 4856.0M(4856.0M)->0.0B(4856.0M) Survivors: 56.0M->56.0M Heap: 5394.6M(8192.0M)->539.7M(8192.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
```

I checked http.log around 19:23:23 and found 404 error and there is no http request between 19:12:22 and 19:23:23 which is wired:

```
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:12:22 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111715/commit HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 270
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:12:22 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 406 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 23
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:12:22 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 406 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 20
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:12:22 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111738/commit HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 30
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:12:22 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 406 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 22
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 281 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 661943
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 1131 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 661771
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 406 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 662613
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1" 201 4156 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 676326
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111741/commit HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 8
188.188.33.66 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111731/commit HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.11-final-0 (linux2)" 0
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111723/commit HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 1
188.188.41.35 - - [17/Mar/2016:19:23:23 +0800] "POST /db/data/transaction/111745/commit HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "py2neo/2.0.8 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/2.7.6-final-0 (linux2)" 0
```

Comment: can you identify which request to the rest api are failing ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen I checked http.log and found something, but it's too long for comment, so I added them to the end of original post. Please see whether it's helpful.

Comment: it seems like a lot of transactions are opened but never actually committed, can you check how do you use your transactions ? Do you handle errors from the py2neo client ? I mean, if the tx fails py2neo will warn it and you should log that somewhere ?

Comment: in my application log, there are two kind of py2neo errors: Deadlock and Http404. About Deadlock, it occurs frequently from beginning of our test, but this is expected since our test data is very special. We handle it by sleep 0.5s and then retry. About Http404, first one occurs at 19:23:23, so I think it's same reason with tx roll back. By the way, I check my application log, it send create node cypher at 19:12:22 and then wait util http404 at 19:23:23, so no request between them. @ChristopheWillemsen